# XSL: counting values from elements with the same name

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am new to the XSL and would appreciate any help with processing a file structured like this:

```
<UniML>
<student>
    <name>Salvatore</name>
        <m value="1">
            <i value="17.5">Balliol College</i>
            <i value="3">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="2.88">Balliol College</i>
            <i value="32.9">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="15.75">Balliol College</i>
        </m>
        <m value="5">
            <i value="26.25">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="8.75">Balliol College</i>
        </m>
</student>

<student>
    <name>Karl</name>
        <m value="1">
            <i value="10.5">Balliol College</i>
            <i value="4.7">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="2.25">Balliol College</i>
            <i value="12.6">Kellogg College</i>
        </m>
        <m value="5">
            <i value="3.75">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="1.25">Balliol College</i>
        </m>
</student>

<student>
    <name>Serenella</name>
        <m value="1">
            <i value="4">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="3.84">Balliol College</i>
            <i value="14.100000000000001">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="6.75">Balliol College</i>
        </m>
        <m value="5">
            <i value="20.25">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="42.75">Balliol College</i>
            <i value="11.25">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="3.75">Balliol College</i>
        </m>
</student>
```

EDIT: I would like to compute the total score for each student m1*(i1+i2+...)+m5*(i1+i2+...) for each college and output is in XHTML with some structure like this:

Salvatore: Balliol score = 1*(17.5+2.88+17.75)+5*(8.8.75), Kellogg score =
Karl: Balliol score =,  Kellogg score =

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your given sample can contain at most one student because `<student>` is the root element. Could you provide a more representative example to show where students are within the overall hierarchy (and preferably a good sample of college values to work with)? Also, what should the result look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kIByVal" match="i" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "i[not(generate-id()=generate-id(key('kIByVal',.)[1]))]"/>

 <xsl:template match="i">
  <college name="{.}" total="{sum(key('kIByVal',.)/@value)}"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<student>
    <name>Salvatore</name>
    <m value="1">
    <i value="17.5">Balliol College</i>
    <i value="3">Kellogg College</i>
    <i value="2.88">Balliol College</i>
    </m>
</student>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<college name="Balliol College" total="20.38"/>
<college name="Kellogg College" total="3"/>
```

---

**II. In case you want to preserve the structure of the document and just "totalize" the `<I>`s :**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kIByVal" match="i" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "i[not(generate-id()=generate-id(key('kIByVal',.)[1]))]"/>

 <xsl:template match="i">
  <i value="{sum(key('kIByVal',.)/@value)}"><xsl:apply-templates/></i>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), again the correct result is produced**:

```
<student>
   <name>Salvatore</name>
   <m value="1">
      <i value="20.38">Balliol College</i>
      <i value="3">Kellogg College</i>
   </m>
</student>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Use of the **[Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.
2. Overriding the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** in the second transformation.

---

**Update**:

In a comment the OP has added a new requirement: each college must have per/student values and the value of each corresponding `i` must be multiplied by the "weight" -- the value of its parent `m`.

**Here is an XSLT 2.0 solution -- it is easier to write than a two-pass XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kIByVal" match="i" use="."/>
 <xsl:key name="kStudentByCollege" match="student"
  use="m/i"/>
 <xsl:key name="kCollegePerStudentPerM" match="i"
  use="concat(generate-id(../..),'+',generate-id(..),'+',.)"/>


 <xsl:template match=
  "i[not(generate-id()=generate-id(key('kIByVal',.)[1]))]"/>

 <xsl:template match="i">
  <college name="{.}">
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="college" select=
    "key('kStudentByCollege', .)">
    <xsl:with-param name="pCollegeName" select="."/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </college>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="student" mode="college">
  <xsl:param name="pCollegeName"/>

  <student name="{name}">
    <xsl:sequence select=
     "sum(m/(@value*sum(key('kCollegePerStudentPerM',
                            concat(generate-id(..),'+',
                                   generate-id(.),'+',$pCollegeName)
                            )/@value
                         )
             )
          )"/>
  </student>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the newly-provided XML document:**

```
<UniML>
    <student>
        <name>Salvatore</name>
        <m value="1">
            <i value="17.5">Balliol College</i>
            <i value="3">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="2.88">Balliol College</i>
            <i value="32.9">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="15.75">Balliol College</i>
        </m>
        <m value="5">
            <i value="26.25">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="8.75">Balliol College</i>
        </m>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Karl</name>
        <m value="1">
            <i value="10.5">Balliol College</i>
            <i value="4.7">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="2.25">Balliol College</i>
            <i value="12.6">Kellogg College</i>
        </m>
        <m value="5">
            <i value="3.75">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="1.25">Balliol College</i>
        </m>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Serenella</name>
        <m value="1">
            <i value="4">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="3.84">Balliol College</i>
            <i value="14.100000000000001">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="6.75">Balliol College</i>
        </m>
        <m value="5">
            <i value="20.25">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="42.75">Balliol College</i>
            <i value="11.25">Kellogg College</i>
            <i value="3.75">Balliol College</i>
        </m>
    </student>
</UniML>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<college name="Balliol College">
   <student name="Salvatore">79.88</student>
   <student name="Karl">19</student>
   <student name="Serenella">243.09</student>
</college>
<college name="Kellogg College">
   <student name="Salvatore">167.15</student>
   <student name="Karl">36.05</student>
   <student name="Serenella">175.6</student>
</college>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, would you be so kind to help me adapting your script on multiple patients? Many thanks.

Comment: @MichalB.Kovac, sure, just a second. Would you like XML output or text output?

Comment: @MichalB.Kovac, Would you like an XSLT 2.0 solution, or are you bound to XSLT 1.0?

Comment: XSLT1.0 is preferred, but not required.

Comment: @MichalB.Kovac, I have provided an XSLT 2.0 solution in an update to this answer.

Comment: Thank you. Extremely appreciated.

Comment: @MichalB.Kovac, You are welcome. I removed an unnecessary template from the last solution, so it isn't so long now.